# Using JavaScript to edit HTML style in .cshtml

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am making a MVC Web Application and trying to edit the width of a progress bar to show an increase or decrease in the progress and am using a basic javascript function to do it but it is not working.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>


<div class="progress progress-striped active progress-sm">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" name="blah" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%"  id="pb1">
        <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Change Width" onclick="increase()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    function increase() {
        var pwidth = document.getElementByID("pb1").style.style="width: 80%";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Put your JS function inside document.ready function.

Comment: `style.style`? Shouldn't it be `style.width = '80%'`?

Comment: `.style.style`,  and `'"width: 80%"'` - too many quote marks.

Comment: @User3250 that shouldn't matter if the script is below the desired HTML.

Comment: @User3250 no need for that in this case. It would matter if the code wasn't using inline event handlers.

Comment: @ADyson Oops! My bad, apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to define the style is wrong. See below (I've also added a background colour to make it easier to see the effect):

```js
function increase()
    {
        document.getElementById("pb1").style.width = '80%';
    }
```

```css
#pb1
{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>


<div class="progress progress-striped active progress-sm">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" name="blah" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%"  id="pb1">
        <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Change Width" onclick="increase()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" />
```

Comment: The background colour isn't working but otherwise, perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: strange, it works fine for me in the snippet here. But glad to help anyway.

Comment: Follow up question, if I want to increase the current progress by 10% rather than giving a static value, how do I do it? The value function doesn't work.

I'm updating the function in the main question.

Comment: @Yash we answered the question as it was asked. If you have a new question please ask a new question and link to it here. I will be happy to help you. I think that's fair on those of us who answered. Otherwise the answers given don't make sense vs the altered question. And people can't get any more reputation for answering the "same" question 3 times over, each time you change the requirements.

Comment: Hey sure, I'll do that then. Sorry, I am new to Stack and did not know how it works.

Comment: No problem, we all have to learn. Put the link to the new question here when you've finished it and I'll take a look

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431074/using-javascript-to-alter-attributes-in-a-mvc-web-application

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fixed version for you, you're setting the width incorrectly.

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>


<div class="progress progress-striped active progress-sm">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" name="blah" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%; border: 1px solid black;"  id="pb1">
        <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Change Width" onclick="increase()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    function increase()
    {
        document.getElementById("pb1").style.width = "80%";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use `jQUery` and attach click event like this -

```js
$('#change-width').on('click',function(){
    $('#pb1').css('width','80%');
    $('#pb1').attr('aria-valuenow','80');
    $('.sr-only').text('80% Complete');
});
```

```css
#pb1
{
  background-color:#09F;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:14px;
  padding:4px;
  border-radius:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
    
    <h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
    <h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
    
    <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
    
    <div class="progress progress-striped active progress-sm">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" name="blah" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%"  id="pb1">
            <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Change Width" id="change-width" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" />
```

> Make sure you update following data while you change the progress bar-
>
> - Width of bar.
> - aria-valuenow attribute
> - Percentage text
>
> To get the correct output.

Comment: What does the aria-valuenow attribute do actually? It works for me even if I don't change that. But this is useful, thanks :)

Comment: Okay I don't know why but this isn't working when I add it to the code though it's working perfectly here.

I am using VS Express for Web/

Comment: Make sure you include jQuery and provide correct path of Js file where you have put the code.